# iPhone 4 free case - replacing phone voids current order?

Tags: iphone

I have recently had my iPhone replaced. An order for the free bumper case had already been placed using my old phone for which I received a confirmation email, but I did not get an email stating that the order had been cancelled when the phone was replaced.

If I launch the free iphone case application I am able to place another order, but I do not want to if my current one is en-route.

Does anyone know what's happening in this scenario?

Comment: Have you tried calling AppleCare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [iPhone 4 Case Program](http://www.apple.com/iphone/case-program/) app allowed me to order another case directly after getting my replacement phone. I was determined to do the right thing and wait to see if my original shipment was fulfilled before ordering another one. It seems that my original order has shipped and I can no longer order another case through the app.

Answer (score 1):

You likely will be able to order, and receive, another case. I had purchased a bumper for my iPhone 4 a few days after I got it, and yet the free case app let me order another case for free in addition to refunding my bumper purchase.